# classic asp - cdo message delivery issue with gmail

Tags: email

I have written code in asp for sending email to my clients.  I am using windows XP with iis5.1, which is, of course, outdated, cdo.message and smtp.gmail.com.  Everything goes on perfectly well.  The emails are generated and send. But I observe that when the emails get delivered to yahoo and other mail servers, it is not shown in Gmail accounts.  Can anybody help how I can get the mail delivered to "xxxxx@gmail.com" also?

`Set objMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")`

```
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="myemail@mailserver.in"
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="mypassword"

objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMsg.From = "myemail@myserver.in"
objMsg.To = "jojysp@gmail.com"
objMsg.Subject = mSub
objMsg.HTMLBody = mText
objMsg.Send
Set objMsg = Nothing
```

Thanks and regards,

Jojy

Answer (score 0):

try this codes below:

```
objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="username@gmail.com"
    objMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="Password"
```